# Wiring DPDT switch to add parallel resistor

Tags: resistors, parallel, dpdt

I'm currently making some modifications to an old synthesizer. I've done a few of the mods sucessfully, but I think the instructions I got for one of them are wrong, and I'm not sure what to do.

I have two separate circuits, and I want to add a parallel resistor to each, and toggle both circuits at the same time. One position would put the parallel resistor in the circuit, the other just leaves the original resistor. The instructions call for a DPDT ON-ON switch. The drawing is from first post:

https://forum.moogmusic.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=22856&start=30

[image]

I did it as he suggested, it's not giving me the expected sound. When I contacted the guy who did it, he said he never actually did one like that, so he wasn't sure it was correct.  Am I supposed to wire this differently than what he had indicated? I almost feel like something should go on the bottom two posts.

Comment: Could you explain a bit what you are really trying to do? So you have an existing circuit where these 120k resistors exist and then you want to connect in parallel to these the 169k? Because in this drawing in the other post, the 169k are connected in series.

Comment: you only need a DPST switch ... you could test the circuit using two pushbutton switches that you press simultaneously

Comment: this site talks about R107 and R109 ... https://www.99musik.se/showthread.php?323874-MG1-stora-modtr%C3%A5den ... here is the schematic ... http://www.oocities.org/gallomagnetix/mg1_control.jpg

Comment: here is a link to the MG-1 service manual from the swedish site ... http://manuals.fdiskc.com/flat/Realistic%20MG-1%20Service%20Manual.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The diagram shown on the link provided does place the 169k resistors in parallel with the original 120k resistors.

If it is not working for you, either you made a wiring error or the author of the link was incorrect about the effect of the paralleled resistors.

Comment: Actually, i think he was wrong. I took the switch out and tried wiring the 169k right to the resistor, and it still did the same thing. I've since also heard from another person on the forum that he was definitely wrong. Thank you for the response.